# Android: set timer to allow opening activity

Tags: android, timer

I have a spin to win activity in my app that user can use to get coins.
i would like to make that after the user use the spinner he would have to wait for 8 hours before being allowed to open the spin activity again.
how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way will be:

- determine those 8 hours from the moment he spinned ->

```
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() + your8hours;
```

- save this data (sharedpreference) ->

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = new SharedPreferences();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MYDURATIONSAVED", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("durationSaved", duration);
    editor.apply();
```

- in the new session, you retrieve the data ->

```
    long alreadyExistingDuration = sharedPreferences.getLong("durationSaved", -1);
```

- and simply compare it in order to check if the user is allowed or not to spin again ->

```
    long check = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(check >=  alreadyExistingDuration){
    allow...
    }
```

if you would have put a sample of your code I would have use it
for example, if you use sqlite, firebase or files to store your data, it may have been a different answer
But the data that you need to store is primitive so sharedpreference should be enough

Comment: Are All Codes to be put inside SpinnerActivity?, or MainActivity that have the button that opens the spinnerActivity